# MacOS MySQL Client Gets Stuck on Query That is a Certain Size

Tags: linux, mysql, php, mac-osx

My MySQL client gets stuck on a query when the output is a certain size. When it's small enough, the query will successfully output. The client is connecting to a remote server (Ubuntu 18.04). When I ran `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` on the server after the query got stuck on the client, it showed the remote client connection as sleeping with no error. The client is a MacOS Mojave (10.14) device.

When I tested the same query on another remote MacOS client that is running a different OS version (Ventura 13.5), it worked just fine. When I press control c on the client that is stuck, it outputs `-- query aborted` but never exits. I have to close and reopen the terminal for the client to be able to run commands again.

I also have an apache server with a php file on the same machine. It's using MySQL in the php file to connect and query the same MySQL server. When I open the php file from a browser, the webpage never loads. I waited for a long while for the webpage to timeout, but I ended up quitting the request assuming it'd be timeout on the web server side.

I tried changing a bunch of settings relating to caching and timing out on the MySQL server, but non of them worked. I think it's most likely device related since two different types of clients on the same machine (shell and php) had the same result. Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

[Screenshot of the client getting stuck from the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl4IB.png)

[Screenshot of the server process list output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyvbT.png)